# How to grup by names by values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to use SQL and make from:

```
Student | Subject 
alpha |Geo
alpha| Maths   
beta |Maths
beta | Geo
gamma |PE
delta  |Maths
alpha | Pe
```

Output: beta

Which student has Geo Maths and but not has Pe?

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select student
from t
group by student
having sum(case when subject = 'Geo' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when subject = 'Maths' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when subject = 'PE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use LISTAGG to form a list of the subjects each student takes, then determine if the subjects you care about either are or are not in the list. Something like:

```
SELECT STUDENT
  FROM (SELECT STUDENT,
               LISTAGG(SUBJECT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STUDENT) AS SUBJECTS
          FROM STUDENTS
          GROUP BY STUDENT)
  WHERE INSTR(SUBJECTS, 'Geo') <> 0 AND
        INSTR(SUBJECTS, 'Maths') <> 0 AND
        INSTR(SUBJECTS, 'Pe') = 0
```

Or you could query for all students taking 'Geo', 'Maths', and 'Pe', then include or exclude as needed. Something like:

```
WITH cteGeo_students
       AS (SELECT STUDENT
             FROM STUDENTS
             WHERE SUBJECT = 'Geo'),
     cteMaths_students
       AS (SELECT STUDENT
             FROM STUDENTS
             WHERE SUBJECT = 'Maths'),
     ctePe_students
       AS (SELECT STUDENT
             FROM STUDENTS
             WHERE SUBJECT = 'Pe')
SELECT g.STUDENT
  FROM cteGeo_students g
  INNER JOIN cteMaths_students m
    ON m.STUDENT = g.STUDENT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePe_students p
    ON p.STUDENT = g.STUDENT
  WHERE p.STUDENT IS NULL
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=118734fae49556c77da0774a6b66a8f7)